# What is an alternative to HTML5 geolocation that I can use with Electron.js?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, electron

My problem is that this code:

```
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => console.log(position))
```

outpust undefined because geolocation requires 'https' context but electron uses the 'file' context.
Is there any alternatives?

Comment: Are you using the latest version? Here it says that it's fixed in the newer version https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1747

Comment: I just updated electron and it still doesn't work.

Comment: have you got your own geolocation API key from Google?

Comment: Thank's ill look into it.